# How can we display MySQL tables in H2 console preserving their original case sensitivity?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, h2, uppercase

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot application with a MySQL database. This database is initially empty and filled dynamically with changelog XML files. So, when I want to see my database into the H2 console, I can only see them in uppercase as they are displayed like this by default. However, what I want is to display them just as they are originally when I create them. For instance, if I create through my XML file a table named "myTable", I want the H2 console to display it in the left sidebar as it is which means like that "myTable" and not like "MYTABLE" as it is by default.

Hence, my question is how I can do that please?

Comment: I'm not sure about MySQL, but generally in SQL databases, if you create a table named `myTable`, it is stored in the metadata as `MYTABLE` or `mytable`. Case is only preserved when the name is quoted (i.e. `"myTable"` in standard SQL).

Comment: So if I create a table named like that "MYTABLE", should I've put it into quotes to preserve it in uppercase or the system will do it automatically?

Comment: Unquoted object names are usually normalized to either uppercase or lowercase, so `mytable`, `myTable`, `MYTABLE`, etc are all one and the same table. However, I'm not sure if this also applies to MySQL (but given the behaviour you observed, it probably is).